# spring mapping for static is not mapped

Tags: java, spring

i have htmls under WebContent html folder

i have below mapping for the static content and I get this message.
Could you please check and tell me whats wrong here

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginApp/html/404ErrorPage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springController'

```
 <bean id="staticPagesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".htm"/>
    </bean>

package com.wachoviasec.login.servlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ErrorController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "errors", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
  public String renderErrorPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

    String errorPage = null; 
    int httpErrorCode = getErrorCode(httpRequest);

    switch (httpErrorCode) {
      case 301: {
        errorPage = "/html/301ErrorPage.htm";
        break;
      }
      case 403: {
        errorPage = "/html/403ErrorPage.htm";
        break;
      }
      case 404: {
        errorPage = "/html/404ErrorPage";
               break;
      }
      case 500: {
        errorPage = "/html/500ErrorPage.htm";
        break;
      }
      case 503: {
        errorPage = "/html/503ErrorPage.htm";
        break;
      }
    }
    return errorPage;
  //  return "redirect:"+errorPage;
 //   return "forward:"+errorPage;
  }

  private int getErrorCode(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    return (Integer) httpRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
  }
}
```

Comment: `prefix = "/", suffix = ".htm"` means that `/html/404ErrorPage` becomes `//html/404ErrorPage.htm` and that `/html/301ErrorPage.htm` becomes `//html/301ErrorPage.htm.htm`. Do you have a file named `//html/301ErrorPage.htm.htm` in your servlet container?

Comment: Andreas, I have removed / and .htm from 500 error condition and it still does not go to the page. The htm file is under MyApp/WebContent/html/500ErrorPage.htm  .

Comment: And if return "forward:"+retunrpage I get this org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginApp/html/500ErrorPage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springController'
and for the redirect it comes back with 404 as 500 page is not found and gives the below message. org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginApp/html/404ErrorPage.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springController'

Comment: I have added this <mvc:resources mapping="/html/**" location="/html/" />
 and now it is working fine for forwards

Answer (score 0):

you're missing .htm on your 404error code :3